# Android Service do not start if it is in a library project

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, library-project

I have a project in which I need a listener service. Everything works fine. But the service is also necessary in other projects. So I created a library project in which I add the service.
But now the service does not start any more.

I start it like before:

*Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

this.startService(intent);*

The service does not react on the event. I put also in onCreate(), onStart() and onStartCommand() a log entry(*Log.d(„MyApp“,“iamhere“)*) to see if it even starts. But there is also nothing in the log.

I can use other classes out of the Library project.

What do I have to do to use the service?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: It needs to be registered in the manifest, as before. Whether you do that in the library's manifest or in the the app's manifest is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it on manifest as suggested. You can also use Broadcast Receivers. Or the type of service you need.

Comment: Thanks. I only add it in the libary project manifest, but didn't change it in the project i want to use it in. Thanks

Comment: That is a common mistake people make and it is good that you brought it up.